# Is there a max. row and column amount of creating a table with Text() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried creating a table according to the below codes. The tables can be created, however as if there's a max row*column limit. When i write 18*18, a table can be created, also 18*19 can be created too. But when i write a 19*19 table, the program is just waiting. 18*19 is 342, and 19*19 is 361. Also a 15*23 table can be created quickly but when i type 15*24, the program is waiting again. The result is same when the row*column is above 350. Is there a solution to solve this problem?

```
from tkinter import *


class Application:
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Database")
        self.window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.canvas = Canvas(borderwidth=0)
        self.frame_1 = Frame(self.canvas, bg="black")
        self.scrollbar_1 = Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbar_2 = Scrollbar(orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_1.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar_2.set)
        self.scrollbar_1.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.scrollbar_2.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame_1, anchor="nw")
        self.frame_1.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)

        self.menubar = Menu(tearoff=0)

        self.table()
        self.menu()
        self.mainloop = self.window.mainloop()

    def table(self):
        row = int(input("Row:"))
        column = int(input("Column:"))
        for i in range(row):
            for j in range(column):
                text = Text(self.frame_1, width=20, height=1)
                text.bind("<Button-3>", self.popup)
                text.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=1, pady=1)
                text.configure(state="disabled")

    def menu(self):
        self.menubar.add_command(label="Copy", command=lambda: self.window.focus_get().event_generate('<<Copy>>'))

    def popup(self, event):
        self.menubar.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))


example = Application()
```

Comment: 19x19 works fine for me. 100x100 works too, though there's about a 2 second delay to create 10,000 text widgets. 20x20 works in the blink of an eye. 15x24 also works just fine.

Comment: I was able to create a 50x50. I think your system is just lacking in power! :P. Also I did try 100x100 but it was taking to long so I force my IDE to exit program. My work computer not so strong.

Comment: What do you mean by "when i type 15*24"? The program is asking for a single number. Do you mean you're entering `15` for rows and `24` for columns?

Comment: Oh, it's my bad English. I wanted to say i write 15 to row and 24 to column, but i said 15*24

Comment: A short time ago i  typed 20 to row and 20 to column and i'm still waiting.

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements to watch as it works through the loops? And just to be clear (because it happens a lot on SO) --  you're saying you see this bad behavior with this exact code? What OS are you using?

Comment: No i haven't tried yet. But i'm trying it now. Yes i see this bad behaviour with this exact code. The OS i am using is Win7. By the way i'm still waiting. :/

Comment: I add a step statement with counting the steps from 1 that print in every loop. When i type 15 to row and 15 to column there is no problem, at last, printed all the 225 steps and while printing the steps, the window is opened. But when i type 20 to row and 20 to column, the program prints 400 steps but doesn't open the window.

Comment: If you remove this line, can you see all of the widgets? `self.frame_1.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)` (that will cause other problems, but it might  yield more information)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Before adding the scroll codes to the whole code, i observed the same problem.

Comment: Do you see no window at all, or a blank window?

Comment: There's no window.

Comment: What happens if you call `self.update()` after your loop, as the last statement in `table`? And immediately before and after that, put in a print statement.

Comment: self.update? But there's no update attribute in the class. By the way i added two print statements.

Comment: My apologies. `self.window.update()`. What did those print statements tell you?

Comment: Yes, now it's creating a 20*20 table and also i tried 50*50 table, it's creating again, 100*100 works too. Thank you very much. Why it needs self.windows.update() ?