# Python & tkinter -> Displaying error while uploading long binary numbers and scrolling the x scrollbar freeze the program

Tags: python, tkinter

According to the below codes;

1. Relatively short texts containing letters can be uploaded to the Text() widget and can be converted to Binary numbers and this binary numbers can be seen in the Text() widget.
2. Relatively long texts containing letters can be uploaded to the Text() and can be converted to Binary numbers but this binary numbers can’t be seen in the Text() widget.  In order to see this numbers, i have to click the mause button-1. This converted numbers can be converted to letters again with no missing. But when i scroll the x axis scrollbar, the program freezes.
3. Relatively short texts containing binary numbers can be uploaded to the Text() widget and can be converted to letters and this letters can be seen in the Text() widget.
4. Relatively long texts contaning binary numbers can be uploaded to the Text() widget can be converted to letters and this letters can be seen in the Text() widget. However when i scroll the binary numbers with x axis scrollbar , the program freezes.
5. The program can get all the paragraphs of the text files and document files contanining letters and characters as they are placed.
6. The program can’t gel all the paragraphs of the text files and document files contanining binary numbers as they are placed. But again, the program can convert them to the text with no missing. However when i click the numbers, the digits are disapearing and appearing by clicking to another place of the Text() widget (See the images).
   [image: Image_1]
   [image: Image_2]
   What i want to do is displaying the binary numbers as they displayed in the text file and scroll the scrollbars to see them clearly. (See the image)
   [image: Image_3]
   When i convert the above binary numbers with the program, the program can display the below image with no displaying error.[image: Image_4]

The codes are below:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()

        self.y_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master=self)
        self.y_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.x_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master=self)
        self.x_scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

        self.text = tk.Text(master=self, width=100, height=25, wrap="none")
        self.text.pack()

        self.configure_widgets()
        self.create_numbers()

    def configure_widgets(self):
        self.y_scrollbar.configure(orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.x_scrollbar.configure(orient="horizontal", command=self.text.xview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.y_scrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=self.x_scrollbar.set)

    def create_numbers(self):
        for i in range(10000):
            self.text.insert("insert", str(i)+" ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    application = App(master=root)
    application.mainloop()
```

Comment: please create a [mcve]. if the problem is with long lines of text in the text widget, we don't need to see all the other code for the menubar.

Comment: Ok, let me change the codes.

Comment: Codes are changed.

Comment: The code you posted works without a problem. How are we supposed to reproduce your problem with that? The code you provide needs to reproduce the problem.

Comment: When i write long texts like on the image which displays binary numbers, the paragraphs can't be formed in the Text() widget and also when i scroll the x scrollbar, the program is freezing. But there's no problem with other texts.

Comment: Ok, so create a program that exhibits that. For example, maybe you can create a function that uses a loop to generate that type of data from random numbers. If we can't duplicate the problem you claim you have, it's nearly impossible for us to fix it.

Comment: I added a function that use a loop to generate numbers, to the program.  if i insert the numbers like "  self.text.insert("insert", str(i)+"\n")  ", there is no displaying error and i can see the numbers by scrolling the y scrollbar without any freezing. But if i insert the numbers like "  self.text.insert("insert", str(i))+' '  ", the numbers are displayed in x axis and when i scroll the x axis, the scrollbar is freezing.

Comment: What i wanted to say is, for example the notepad's x scrollbar has a limit in scrolling, when the characters are horizontally more than x scrollbar limit, the characters which exceed the scrollbar limit are written in a new row. But in the codes that i wrote, x scrollbar grows longer and is freezing when scrolling.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question that generates input. Once again, _if we can't duplicate the problem, we can't help fix it_.

Comment: Oh, sorry. i have just written the code that generates input.

Comment: After adding the code that generate numbers, the problem is scrolling the x scrollbar, the program is freezing when i scroll the x scrollbar.

Comment: I still don't see the UI freeze. It works fine for me. What platform are you running on?

Comment: I use Pycharm and the os is Windows7. If you remember, a few days later you helped me to solve in  another thread which is about freezing. And in that topic, you said also the program works fine for you however later you wrote a code which is like self.window.update(). You suggested me that to put this code at the last step of the for loop. And then my problem was solved. For you, in this topic, is the problem same with the another thread. The topic link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575238/is-there-a-max-row-and-column-amount-of-creating-a-table-with-text-in-tkinter